# Event ID 6009: is this event triggered only when a user-initiated shutdown has occurred?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, windows-event-log

Like the title says.  From what I've briefly read, 6009 occurs when CTRL-ALT-DEL or Start > Shutdown is initiated by a user.  If a shutdown sequence is initiated by SYSTEM for example, would this event also be logged?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Event 6009](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/196452) is logged at startup, not at shutdown. It contains only a string identifying the operating system version. It's been that way since NT 4.0 or so.

If you're looking for a system initiated shutdown/restart, look for [event 1074](https://web.archive.org/web/20160519064523/https://www.microsoft.com/technet/support/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=Windows%20Operating%20System&ProdVer=5.2&EvtID=1074&EvtSrc=User32&LCID=1033). The details for this event will tell you what process initiated the restart and what reason was given, and you can [check the reason code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376885%28VS.85%29.aspx) for further information about why the system shut down or restarted.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Michael Hampton for clarifying that 6009 is on startup.

To answer the OP's question, is there a 6009 after a system initiated shutdown? Yes, it appears so. There is a 6009 once the computer starts up after a system shutdown. (System shutdowns are event id 1074, like Michael says).

Here's a nice powershell to display both of these events so you can see for yourself that 6009's follow 1074's:

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName = "System"; Id = 1074, 6009; }
```